# Change background image opacity with css

Tags: html, css

I want to change header's background image opacity with css. Could you help me please.

```css
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1910/500/nature/) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header class="intro">
  ...
</header>
```

Comment: Four upvotes for something you can google in a minute? Not very compliant with OP's user name.

Comment: In modern browsers, you can also make use of CSS3's `filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the opacity in programs like Photoshop or GIMP.

Or you can do that with `opacity` in css. But you probably don't want that since you will have some content in your `.intro` which will then also be affected by it.

So I suggest following solution

```
.intro {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}


.intro:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg'); 
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : 0.2;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q63nf0La/

Basically you add `:after` element that will be a background image , you position it `absolute` ( your `.intro` will need to be `position:relative;` ) and then you set the `z-index` and `opacity`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now I want to do the same for another div but it seems I do something wrong. Could you help me please. .download-section {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-color: #000; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with what you have currently?
the process should be the same for other elements. But I will look into it if you give full example.

Comment: I'm sorry but did you even look what I did? I just repeated my step and it works fine. Are you trolling maybe?

http://jsfiddle.net/292zxcqw/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! There was smth wrong in my code.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative would be that you convert this background image file to the .PNG format and make the original image 0.2 opacity using a photo editing program but if you insist on using CSS, you can use the method below:

Since CSS does not directly support background image opacity, you can try using a pseudo-class to overlay another on your header and set opacity on it. Something along the lines of this should help:

```
<header class="intro">
...
</header>

.intro {
    position: relative;
    background: #5C97FF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* You could use :after - it doesn't really matter */
.intro:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

HTML code

```
<header class="intro">
<img class="IntroImg" src="../img/bg.jpg">
</header>
```

CSS code

```
.intro introIimg:hover {
opacity: 1.0;//Set your opacity
...

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

There is no CSS property background-opacity, but you can fake it by inserting a pseudo element with regular opacity the exact size of the element behind it.

```css
.intro {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 100px 0;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #000;
}

.intro:after {
 content : "";
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 opacity : 0.2;
 z-index: -1;
 background: url(https://t1.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/81/10/58/240_F_81105881_pmBwtzXqFmtFx6rfhujAqTnhpWZf8fXn.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header class="intro">
  ...
</header>
```

See the link [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes